# Как правильно задать тип в Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Как правильно в Typescript задать тип для массива, в котором могут быть и null, и string одновременно? Какой синтаксис правильный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let array: (string | null)[] = ['string', null];`

Answer (score 2):

`let array: [string, null] = ['1', null];`

Comment: Неверно, получится кортеж

Comment: @Enkei, нет) --

Comment: Ответ безусловно правильный, а кортеж зависит только от того, какой массив будет поставлен, если он небольшой, то данные необходимо указывать явно, если же там весьма объемные значения, то необходимо ставить уже `any` , но по данному вопросу этот ответ является более правильным

Comment: @meine возможно я не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Да, такая запись безусловно возможна, но я ожидал решение, которое дали выше. В любом случае спасибо

Answer (score 0):

let array: any[] = ['1', null];

Comment: any - подразумевает любой тип данных, следовательно в массив можно добавлять не только строки и null, но и числа, объекты и т.д. Typescript на то и типизирован, чтобы использовать в нем типы, а не превращать его в Javascript.